# Change canvas width and height without losing the current draw

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm creating a pixel art app and when I want to save the image from the canvas the image is so small, so it seems pixelated when I want to resize it.

I want to resize it to bigger dimensions, but I don't know how.

This is the code example:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red'; 
ctx.fill();

document.write('<img style="width:300px;" src="'+c.toDataURL("image/png")+'"/>');

// This is an image with dimensions 108x108px and it seems very bad when i resize it to 300x300px
// I want to download the canvas image with more resolution
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="108" height="108" style="width: 300px; height:300px;">

</canvas>
```

Comment: Set the `width` and `height` properties on the `c` element.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a canvas and put the imageData in it.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 0, 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(0, 25, 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(25, 0, 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.fill();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(25, 25, 25, 25);
ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx.fill();

var c2 = document.createElement("canvas");
c2.width = 50;
c2.height = 50;
var ctx2 = c2.getContext("2d");
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
ctx2.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

document.write('<img style="width:300px;" src="' + c2.toDataURL("image/png") + '"/>');
```